# 0/1 Knapsack and colored items with conditions

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to solve this 0/1 Knapsack problem:

We have N items with each item characterized by weight, price and color (white, blue, red or black).

We have to choose 12 items with **maximum** total price such as the sum of their weight is <= **W** and the chosen items fulfill these conditions:

- only 1 white item
- between 3 and 5 blue items
- between 3 and 5 red items
- between 1 and 3 black items

I tried this backtracking solution which work fine:

```
int go(int i, int numW, int numBlue, int numR, int numBlack, int currWeight) {
    if (i == N)
        // checkMin check that we have the minumum number of each colored item
        return (checkMin(numW, numBlue, numR, numBlack) && numW + numBlue + numR + numBlack == 12) ? 0 : -10000; 
    int res = -10000;
    res = max(res, go(i + 1, numW, numBlue, numR, numBlack, currWeight));
    //canAddItem check if we can add current item without exceeding the max Weight and not excedding the max number of each colored item
    if (canAddItem(items[i], numW, numBlue, numR, numBlack, currWeight)) {  
        if (items[i].color.equals("W")) numW++;
        if (items[i].color.equals("Blue")) numBlue++;
        if (items[i].color.equals("R")) numR++;
        if (items[i].color.equals("Black")) numBlack++;
        res = max(res, items[i].value + go(i + 1, numW, numBlue, numR, numBlack, (items[i].weight + currWeight)));
    }
    return res;
}

boolean checkMax(int numW, int numBlue, int numR, int numBlack) {
    return numW <= 1 && numBlue <= 5 && numR <= 5 && numBlack <= 3;
}

boolean checkMin(int numW, int numBlue, int numR, int numBlack) {
    return numW == 1 && numBlue >= 3 && numR >= 3 && numBlack >= 1;
}

boolean canAddItem(Item item, int numW, int numBlue, int numR, int numBlack, int currWeight) {
    if (item.color.equals("W")) numW++;
    if (item.color.equals("Blue")) numBlue++;
    if (item.color.equals("R")) numR++;
    if (item.color.equals("Black")) numBlack++;
    currWeight += item.cost;
    return checkMax(numW, numBlue, numR, numBlack) && currWeight <= W && numW + numDef + numMid + numAtt <= 12;
}
```

This work fines but with an exponential complexity so I tried to add memoization (caching) but it doesn't work anymore.

Backtrack without memoization, gives correct answer: https://ideone.com/aPdZjZ

Same code and input but with memoization gives wrong answer: https://ideone.com/wPqxBG

Can any body explain why the memoization doesn't work here, or share his personal approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Note that the number of possibilities is at most C(N, 12). Still huge, but polynomial, not exponential. Dificult to help you more without a complete code (MWE), that we can compile and test directly.

Comment: @Damien C(100,12) = 1050421051106700, I dont think it's an option, I added the missing methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying state variables like `numW, numBlue, etc.` in `go` function in your DP solution. Try [here](https://ideone.com/zohCud).
After making the below correction, it seems to work. Haven't checked overall correctness but the backtracking and DP solution both give same answer.

```
    if (canAddItem(items[i], numW, numBlue, numR, numBlack, currSpent)) {
        if (items[i].color.equals("W")) numW++;
        if (items[i].color.equals("Blue")) numBlue++;
        if (items[i].color.equals("R")) numR++;
        if (items[i].color.equals("Black")) numBlack++;
        res = max(res, items[i].value + go( i + 1, numW, numBlue, numR, numBlack, (items[i].cost + currSpent)));
        if (items[i].color.equals("W")) numW--;
        if (items[i].color.equals("Blue")) numBlue--;
        if (items[i].color.equals("R")) numR--;
        if (items[i].color.equals("Black")) numBlack--;            
    }
```